# SIMD/SSE code crashes on Windows 8 running clearly on Windows 7 and Linux

Tags: c++, windows, sse, simd

I have report of an application (makeahmap) crashes while executing SIMD code:

https://github.com/artyom-beilis/makeahmap/blob/master/sources/makeahmap.cpp#L947

I can not reproduce the issue with exactly the same inputs on my machine:

- Neither Windows 7 that I use my windows development
- Nor on Linux - more than that, the program runs flawlessly with 0 errors under valgrind.
- All loads and stores are unaligned and all values have large margins for loading and saving 16 bytes unaligned data.
- The program is 32bit and built using mingw-g++

Question:

1. What kind of tools can help me to find the reason of the crash at user's PC?
2. What things may be missing?

Comment: I seem to recall that gcc had this bug when it sometimes incorrectly presumed that stack is 16-bytes aligned. Trying `-mstackrealign` won't harm I think

Comment: I'm not clicking a link to look at your code; the relevant parts of it should be here.  A guess: Does the customer's CPU support the SSE instructions you're using?

Comment: Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 won't install on a processor that lacks support for SSE, SSE2, NX, or PAE. All x64 processors must support these, so the OS also forces a check for 32-bit as well. See [Windows 8.x system requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12660/windows-8-system-requirements). It also means you can't count on SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.x, or AVX and must check for processor support so verify you aren't using one of those instructions. Seems likely that the application isn't ensuring aligned memory allocations in all cases and just gets lucky on Windows 7.

Comment: It looks like a case of http://www.peterstock.co.uk/games/mingw_sse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

1. Windows uses 4 byte stack alignment
2. The default stack alignment GCC uses in 16 byte. It fixes the alignment in main/winmain but it does not work for functions called from external threads as 16 byte alignment is not guaranteed.

Solution:

Add `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer))`  attribute to the function called from the thread.

Comment: Thanks to @Ap31 that gave me the direction to solution